# Moving through array elements for calculation

Tags: arrays, function, mean, temperature

Currently my program is reading inputs from a .txt file and it consist of 6480 readings in total. I then assign it accordingly to a 2 Dimensional Array where the first dimension represents days and second dimension represents the number of readings per day. There are 3 months which is results in 90 days and there is 6 reading per hr(for a duration of 12 hours) so its 72 readings per day

```
float readings[90][72];
int days, rperday;

for(days=0; days<90; days++){
 for(rperday=0; rperday<72; rperday++){
    scanf("%f", &readings[days][rperday]);
    printf("{%d %d %.2f}", days, rperday, readings[days][rperday]);
 }
}
```

I'm currently unsure of how to manipulate the for loops in order for me to calculate the hourly mean for that current day. An example would be `readings[0][0] - readings[0][11]` would be the reading for the 1st hour. Subsequently, `readings[0][12] - readings[0][17]` would be the reading for the 2nd hour.

The current code I have right now is this: for this code I'm unsure of how to manipulate the variable x in order to make the variable a jump from 0-11, 12-17 and so on.

```
for(months=0; months<3; months++){
        for(i=months*30; i<(months+1)*30; i++){
    for (j=0; j<72;j++){
        sumperday += readings[i][j];
        for(x=0; x<12; x++){
            for(a=x*6; a<(x+1)*6; a++){
                sumperhr += readings[i][a];
            }                   
            meanperhr = sumperhr/6;
            printf("Day [%d] Hour [%d] MeanPerHr is %.2f\n", i,x,meanperhr);
            sumperhr=0;
        }

    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

what about something like (pseudo code)

```
for(int i=0 ; i + 30 < 90 ; i++){
  int mean = 0;
  for(int j = i; j < 30 + i; j++){
    for(int k = 0; k < 72; k++){
      mean = mean + reading[j][k];
    }
  }
  mean_arr[i] = mean;
}
```